# Docker image runs fine on local machine, but fails with "/usr/local/bin/scrapyd -n: Unknown command: scrapyd" when deployed on heroku

Tags: python, docker, heroku, scrapy, scrapyd

This is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY CollegeXUniversityDataScraper ./CollegeXUniversityDataScraper/

COPY scrapyd.conf ./

ENTRYPOINT [ "scrapyd"]
```

It is running perfectly fine over the port configured in the scrapyd.conf file. But when I build the same and deploy on heroku, it does not seem to work.

This is what I get back in return

```
State changed from crashed to starting
2023-03-22T09:12:44.063518+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `scrapyd`

.....

/usr/local/bin/scrapyd -n: Unknown command: scrapyd
Process exited with status 0
State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: What in your Dockerfile installs `scrapyd` at all?  The error message includes a `-n` option; is this somehow related to how you're running the container?

Comment: Scrapyd is installed "RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt". 
I've not explicitly mentioned the -n option anywhere, it comes up on its own.

Comment: Are you using [the `heroku.yml` workflow](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml) (using the container stack), or the [container registry workflow](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime) (with `heroku container:push`)?

Comment: @Chris I am using the container registry workflow. I have an M1 machine, so I am using docker buildx to build the image, and then I'm pushing it to the registry to deploy